# How can I get jade/express to output the full path in anchor links?

Tags: express, pug

I would like my links to be full absolute paths to the resource being linked without me having to hard code the scheme and URI to the resource. I wish to do this in relation to using `itemprop='url'` on links to have the full url appear in the `href` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches. The first one I would suggest is a basic helper function passed to jade during the rendering. Perhaps bound to the current request:

In your express code:

```
function absolute(req, url) {
    //you'll need more logic here, but this is the concept
    return req.originalUrl + url;
}

res.render("somePage", {absolute: absolute.bind(null, req)});
```

In your jade markup:

```
a(itemprop=url, href=absolute(url))
//- This is assuming "url" is a variable with a string like "/cars/42"
```